# Loading Venn diagram library error invalid syntax

Tags: python

I am trying to use https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn library to generate Venn diagram. But when I load the library, I get this error

File "/opt/mypython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/venn/_venn.py", line 101

```
    def draw_venn(*, petal_labels, dataset_labels, hint_hidden, colors, figsize, fontsize, legend_loc, ax):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any solution for this? I remember using this library before without any problem. Is ther any other alternatives? I need to generate Venn diagram with 4 sets.

Comment: that library only supports python 3.x, you've installed it into python2.7

Comment: from the examples, it looks like it is for python 2.7. I also got some error of unsupported function if I use python 3. it means the library is meant for python 2.7

Comment: btw, this is the actual library -- not the one that was linked: https://github.com/LankyCyril/pyvenn/blob/1d603316f257515eb4732a34b40f2901516111ad/venn/_venn.py#L101